# Want to handle change text input with decimal?

Tags: reactjs

I want to do a handle change for a text input where you can write in decimals like 1.3, 4.5 etc. I have a slider which is connected to this input. I want it to also change while you type inside the input. I have tried out parseFloat, but it is not working. So it means somehow that the input must allow dot?

Here is my code:

```
import {FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';


handleChange1(e) {
this.setState({
  Radius: e.target.value
});}


 <FormControl
          disabled={!Enabled}
          className="size-inputs"
          type="text"
          value={Radius}
          data-name="radius"
          onChange={this.handleChange1}
        />
        <Slider
          disabled={!Enabled}
          className="upload-slider"
          onChange={this.handleSlider2Change}
          min={0}
          max={10}
          value={Radius}
          step={0.1}
        />
```

Comment: This depends a lot on where you got `FormControl` and `Slider`, can you elaborate which library are you importing them from?

Comment: @Amit FormControl is from bootstrap, and slider is from 'rc-slider'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2). Two is the number of decimals.

Comment: I have tried this before, but then the input won't type somehow. :c

Comment: Have you debugged the value out? You may need to do a toString() on the FormControl component

Comment: Try to use value={this.state.Radius}

Comment: @Richard I have two similar sliders and input which is working, but they dont have decimal.